# Find a site slug with Liquid Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, slug

I want to do some layout modifications in Liquid Shopify based on the slugs.

So basically, if the slug exists, add a subpage.
My subpage is working fine with no issues, using `{% subpage "section2"  with "section2"%}`
but I can't get the `IF` working.

I tried this with no luck:

```
{% if site.slug.has_section2? %}
{% subpage "section2"  with "section2"%}
{% endif %}
```

I can't just include 20 subpages because if they don't exist, Shopify will throw an error. But I need to have the possibility of 20.

EDIT

In **pages_show_basic_wide.html** I currently have

```
{% subpage "section1"  with "section1"%}    

{% subpage "section2"  with "section2"%}

{% subpage "section3" with "section3" %}

{% subpage "section4" with "section4" %}
```

The problem is I only want to call each one IF they exist. Otherwise the webpage throws an error.

**_section2.html** contains

```
<section id="section2" class="section2color">
  <div>
    <h4>{{ page.headline }}</h4>
  </div>
  {{ page.basic.content }}
</section>
<div class="section3color">
  <svg class="section2triangle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 Z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

(each section looks like `section2`, but each calls for a different color-code)

Comment: What do you mean by the test on attribute `.has_section2`? Also - is it possible you're `{% render ...`-ing the `subpage` snippet with `section2`? (subpage is not a tag/object, that I can see: https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects)

Comment: my snippet and subpage are called the same thing.

Comment: Can you update your Q with the render tag & include the snippet file itself? Would help me to understand.

Comment: @cameronhurd info added (I think)

Comment: Does this actually work in your Shopify theme? I can't find any documentation on the `{% subpage %}` tag.

Comment: AH! Are you using liquid in a context other than shopify? Like nationbuilder, perhaps? https://nationbuilder.com/liquid_basics ? Might be worthwhile clarifying that & removing the `shopify` tag from this Q.

Comment: I was told NationBuilder uses Shopify, that it's the same language?

Comment: Liquid is a templating language built by the folks at Shopify, but there are independent implementations of it. Nationbuilder appears to have their own!